# Only one line executed in a false IF - PHP

Tags: php, variables, session

I'm integrating pagination to a wordpress block, what should happen is whenever i click "older posts" button, the post offset is incremented in another php file (the block file and the increment files are separate files).

Whenever I click the older posts however some magic happens that shouldn't:

The problem is with one of the if statements, what happens is that IF statement evaluates to false, yet that one line that I marked in the code still gets executed (the echo doesn't execute but the `$_SESSION["inf"] = 0;` does).

Here is the code.

```
if(isset($_POST["paginate_btn"])){
    if(isset($_SESSION["inf"])){
        echo "PREVIOUS:".(string)($_SESSION["inf"]);
        $_SESSION["inf"] = $_SESSION["inf"] + 5;
        echo "<br/> incremented by 5, RESULT:".(string)($_SESSION["inf"]);
    }
    else{
        echo "<br/> isset session inf failed, set to 5";
        $_SESSION["inf"] = 5;
    }
}
else if(isset($a) and ($a != $url)){
        echo "<br/>dif page";
        if(isset($_SESSION["inf"])){
            echo "<br/> unset";
            $_SESSION["inf"] = 0; <----- THIS LINE HERE!
        }
        else{
            echo "<br/>session inf not set and button not pressed";
        }
}
else{
    echo "<br/> button not pressed, a is not set and is same page";
    $_SESSION["inf"] = 0;
}
```

I've messed around with this for hours and hours, I don't understand what the case is here..

`var_dump((isset($a) and ($a != $url)));`evaluates `false`, yet still only that one line of code there gets executed, the echo doesn't, not even the dif page echo before it....

And the funny part, if I comment out that one line, this no longer happens, I've even tried setting it to different variables there so it definitely gets run solo somehow.

Var_dump code after the if statements.

```
echo "<br/>--1---<br/>";
var_dump((isset($a) and ($a != $url)));
echo "<br/>--2---<br/>";
var_dump((isset($_SESSION["inf"])));
echo "<br/>---<br/>";
echo $_SESSION["inf"];
echo "<br/>---<br/><br/>";
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$_SESSION["inf"]` is non-zero when you start the `if` conditions? Is it definitely that line, and not the other line that is setting `$_SESSION["inf"]` to zero?

Comment: Jep, for example if I set it to 27 on that particular line, $_SESSION["inf"] is 27 before the if conditions on the next refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Another part of the code sets `$_SESSION["inf"]` to `0`.

If you don't see the `echo`s, they don't get executed.

Comment: That is what I thought, however, it's not just the 0, if I set that particular line to force $_SESSION["inf"] to 27 instead for example, it sets it to 27 on the next run, and if I comment that line out, it no longer gets reset there (even if the echos don't get executed).

Comment: redirect? but I assume you see the rest of the `echo`s. post a minimal example that reproduces the problem. No offence, but I don't trust your judgement/reasoning.

Comment: The older news button reloads the same page and try's to increment 5 to it. Each time I reload, the number is reset to the same as I set on that line, here is the output (with that line set to `$_SESSION["inf"] = 32;` , it is exactly the same every time I press older news.

http://imgur.com/xEvaOTO

Comment: you're not listening.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you are asking

Comment: post a minimal example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried it and the minimal example works, the part in the main code still doesn't so it must be something deeper in the template. I'll keep digging.